# Evaluating derivative of a multi variable function using chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

My question in given an homogeneous of degree 3 function $f(x,y)$ satisfying $f(6,9)=54$, find the value of $g'(2)$ when $g(t)=f(0.5t^2, 0.25t^3+1)$. 
Can anyone help me with that explaining the concept of the chain rule? Or at least refer me to a good book/site?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just a hunch, but do you perhaps have a typo? Perhaps you meant $g(t) = f(0.5t^2,0.25 t^3 + 1)$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. How did you guess? I figured it out any way. Thanks.

Comment: because this question is an application of the chain rule and Euler's theorem on HOMOGENEOUS functions (like $ f$). your previous question made it imposible to apply Euler's theorem. Also is your question about chain rule specific to this case or do you want to know in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
  &\mathbb R\overset{\gamma}{\longmapsto}&\mathbb R^2&\overset{f}{\longmapsto}\mathbb R\\
  &t\longmapsto&(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))&\longmapsto f(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))
\end{cases}$$

So, $g(t)=f\circ\gamma(t)=f(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$

The chain rule can be understood geometrically: The variation for $f$ is its gradient $\nabla f=(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y})$ and it has to be computed along the direction of the curve curve $\gamma$, so is, along its tangent vector $\gamma'(t)=(\gamma_1'(t),\gamma_2'(t))$. So is, $g'(t)$ is the variation of $f$ along the curve $\gamma$.

$g'(t)=\nabla f(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))\boldsymbol{\cdot}\gamma'(t)=\nabla f(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))\boldsymbol{\cdot}(\gamma_1'(t),\gamma_2'(t))=(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x})\boldsymbol{\cdot}(\gamma_1'(t),\gamma_2'(t))$

$g'(t)=\gamma'_1(t)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\gamma'_2(t)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, with the partials evaluated at $(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$

---

First of all, as the function is homogeneous of degree three $f(3·2,3·3)=3^3f(2,3)=54$, so $f(2,3)=2$

Now $g'(t)=t\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+0.75t^2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ with the partials evaluated at $(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$

$g'(2)=2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(2,3)+3\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(2,3)$

But the Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem states that $x\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=nf(x,y)$ being $n$ the degree, $3$ in this case.

$2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+3\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3f(2,3)$

Then $g'(2)=2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+3\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3f(2,3)=3·2=6$